# AWS websocket container cdk ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cdk

```
lass TestEcsConstruct extends core.Construct {
constructor(scope, id, props) {
    super(scope, id);

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'MyVpc', {
        enableDnsSupport: true,
        enableDnsHostnames: true,
        cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
        maxAzs: 2,
        natGateways: 0,
        subnetConfiguration: [
            {
                cidrMask: 24,
                name: 'Public',
                subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
            }]
    });
    const secGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'SecGroup',
        {
            vpc: vpc,
            description: 'Access to the ECS hosts that run containers',
            allowAllOutbound: true
        }
    );
    secGroup.connections.allowToAnyIpv4(new ec2.Port({
        protocol: ec2.Protocol.TCP,
        fromPort: 22,
        toPort: 22
    }), 'Ingress SSH from public sg');
    secGroup.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(new ec2.Port({
        protocol: ec2.Protocol.TCP,
        fromPort: 22,
        toPort: 22
    }), 'Ingress SSH from public sg');
    secGroup.connections.allowToAnyIpv4(new ec2.Port({
        protocol: ec2.Protocol.TCP,
        fromPort: 8080,
        toPort: 8080
    }), 'Ingress Docker Port Open');
    secGroup.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(new ec2.Port({
        protocol: ec2.Protocol.TCP,
        fromPort: 8080,
        toPort: 8080
    }), 'Ingress Docker Port Open');

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'Ec2Cluster', {
        vpc
    });
    const autoScaleGroup = cluster.addCapacity('DefaultAutoScalingGroup', {
        instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
        keyName: 'default-keypair',
        minCapacity: 1,
        maxCapacity: 2,
        desiredCapacity: 1,
        // resourceSignalTimeout: core.Duration.minutes(5),
        // rollingUpdateConfiguration: {
        //     minInstancesInService: 1,
        //     maxBatchSize: 1,
        //     pauseTime: core.Duration.minutes(5),
        //     waitOnResourceSignals: true,
        //     suspendProcesses: [
        //         'HealthCheck',
        //         'ReplaceUnhealthy',
        //         'AZRebalance',
        //         'AlarmNotification',
        //         'ScheduledActions'
        //     ]
        // }
    });
    autoScaleGroup.addSecurityGroup(secGroup);

    // create a task definition with CloudWatch Logs
    const logging = new ecs.AwsLogDriver({
        streamPrefix: "websocket-app",
        logRetention: 365
    })

    const image = ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset(path.join(path.resolve(), 'test-docker'));
    const taskDefinition = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, "MyTaskDefinition");
    const container = taskDefinition.addContainer("AppContainer", {
        image: image,
        cpu: 256,
        memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
        environment: [('REGION', process.env.REGION),
        ('QUEUE_URL', core.Fn.importValue(
            'NetworkStack:ApiMsgQueueUrl'
        ))],
        logging: logging
    });
    container.addPortMappings({
        containerPort: 8080,
        hostPort: 8080
    });

    // Instantiate ECS Service with just cluster and image
    new ecs.Ec2Service(this, "Ec2Service", {
        cluster,
        taskDefinition
    });
}
```

}

I have this code and cannot seem to even contact this endpoint within the localhost of the ecs container. This example was just to show an open port accessible from outside address, I really am confused on what I am missing here. It seems that inside the container that I connect to there is just an ecs instance docker watcher, but no other docker instance running, I am unable to docker exec into the container that does exist either. Please any advice and or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently related to the memory being 1024 and not 512 also in unrelated topic I was using the wrong image when configuring my own AutoScalingGroup in a related piece of code. So if someone is having issues in that regard please by sure that your machineImage is of the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

```
//'.addCapacity' creates the ASG
const prerenderCluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'prerenderCluster',{
  vpc,
});

prerenderCluster.addCapacity('DefaultAutoScalingGroup', {
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE),
  machineImage: new ecs.EcsOptimizedAmi(),
```

For future, here's an example of what @thekevshow is talking about in regards the correct AMI.